# Why BroadcastReceiver could crash when using MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

I have strange situation in my BroadcastReceiver which uses MediaPlayer. Application crashes after certain number of playing mp3 file.

So, I have Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initButtons();
    }

    private void onStartButtonClicked()
    {
        Intent service = new Intent("com.ggspot.action.LAUNCH_MY_SERVICE");
        startService(service);
    }

    protected void onStopButtonClicked()
    {
        MyAlarm.stop(this);
    }

    private void initButtons()
    {
        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onStartButtonClicked();
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onStopButtonClicked();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This activity launch my service by pressing button

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        MyAlarm alarm = new MyAlarm(getApplicationContext(), 3);
        return START_STICKY;
    }    
}
```

Service just creates BroadcastReceiver

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public MyAlarm()
    {
    }

    public MyAlarm(Context context, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),
                timeoutInSeconds * 1000, pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/music/beep-7.mp3");

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
        player.start();
    }

    public static void stop(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

File **/music/beep-7.mp3** is just short beep sound which last less than half second.

My AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ggspot.action.LAUNCH_MY_SERVICE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyAlarm">
    </receiver>
</application>
```

So, I expect that after pressing Start button I would hear beeping once in three seconds. Beeping will continue even if I close application. In order to stop beeping, I should launch activity and press Stop button. 
What I have now is really strange for me:

- after pressing Start button I hear beeping 7 times and than application crashes
- after pressing button "Force close" after crash I can hear beeping again 7 times. And then I suppouse service is crashed.

I don't understand LogCat so well. It says:
**Unable to start receiver com.ggspot.test.services.MyAlarm: java.lang.NullPointerException**
But I don't understand where. And why only after seventh try to play mp3 file.

**Updated:**

LogCat trace:

```
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.ggspot.test.services.MyAlarm: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1809)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at com.ggspot.test.services.MyAlarm.onReceive(MyAlarm.java:58)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1798)
10-09 08:42:23.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12578):    ... 10 more
```

**Updated**
Solution is adding CompletionListener to media player and release it after mp3 is played:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/music/beep-7.mp3");

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
    player.start();

    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            mp.release();                
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post all of the LogCat errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reading the LogCat**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ggspot.test.services.MyAlarm.onReceive(MyAlarm.java:58)
```

This says that the NullPointerException occurred on line 58 in MyAlarm.java.

**Problem**
I believe you are trying to use a repeating alarm to replay `beep-7.mp3`, this is incorrect.  When the second alarm calls `onReceive()` your are trying to re-create your MediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
```

but you never *released* the first one, only one copy of this MediaPlayer can exist at any time. So the second `player` is `null` and `player.start()` (line 58) throws the NullPointerException:

**Solution**
To repeat `beep-7.mp3`, simply use [`MediaPlayer#setLooping()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29):

```
player.setLooping(true);
```

When you are done with the MediaPlayer you *must* call `player.release()` before trying to create a second MediaPlayer or you may have the same problem.